# Siblings and children I have some

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Siblings and children I have some,

And my mother's husband is my father's son.

Who am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are (or at least could be)

> [Oedipus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oedipus)

Because

> "my father's son" is potentially self-referential. In that case, you would be your mother's husband. Oedipus killed his father and *married his mother*. If he only knew...